# How to rewrite /foo-bar to foo-bar.html but /foo/bar to foo-bar.html using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite `/foo-bar` to `foo-bar.html` but `/foo/bar` to `foo--bar.html` using mod_rewrite?

In other words, replace all slashes in the request URI with `--`, then append `.html`.

I wrote the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Take care of /foo/bar and /foo-foo/bar-bar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1--$2.html [L]

# Take care of /foo, or /foo-bar-baz-whatever-no-slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

This seems to work on some servers but on mine it seems to mess up the rewrites:

> The requested URL `/foo.html/bar` was not found on this server.

It seems to append the `.html` too early.

Any ideas on how to fix this, and what is causing it to fail on this particular server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your example isn't working.  Supplying the apache vesion you are using would help a lot.  I was able to replicate the issue with Apache/2.2.14

If you remove the RewriteBase Directive and go with 
Apache/2.2.14

`RewriteEngine On`

```
# Take care of /foo/bar and /foo-foo/bar-bar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1--$2.html [L]

# Take care of /foo, or /foo-bar-baz-whatever-no-slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

you should have better luck.

In the future look turn up your log level for easier debugging of what's going on.

```
   #don't leave this on in production
   RewriteLog "/private/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
   RewriteLogLevel 5
```

Comment: Weird, it seems to work without the `RewriteBase` directive. Any clue why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One case where this seems to happen is when [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) is enabled, but [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) is set to `Off` (or `Default` and the handler doesn't accept path info), and `foo.html` exists.

Apache notices that your request for `/foo/bar` doesn't point to a real resource, and maps it to `/foo.html` with the path info of `/bar`. Because path info is not allowed, Apache returns a 404 for the request. Likewise, `mod_rewrite` doesn't perform a rewrite because `/foo.html` now is an existing file.

The solution for this scenario would be to turn off `MultiViews` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```